# Deserialize array of objects with dynamic property name

Tags: java, jackson

I have a service that accepts JSON like this

```
[
   {
      "key1": "value1"
   },
   {
      "key2": "value2"
   },
   {
      "key3": "value3"
   }
]
```

And I'm trying to find a way how to deserialize it. I've tried List<Map.Entry<String, String>> (and several concrete implementations) but it does not work. Any ideas how can I map dynamic property names?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic property names are a nightmare (are there any rules regarding the key names?). You should aim for a structure like this:

```
[
   {
      "key": "key1"
      "value": "value1"
   },
   {
      "key": "key2"
      "value": "value2"
   },
   {
      "key": "key3"
      "value": "value3"
   }
]
```

You could archieve this by altering the input json string to match said structure. Then passing it into a normal json parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `List` to deserialize it, then cast all retrieved items to `Map`. This is possible, because Jackson will internally deserialize each array element as a `Map` (as a generic fallback).

```java
List<?> list = objectMapper.readValue(new File("1.json"), List.class);
// assuming there exists an item
Map<?,?> item1 = list.get(0);
// .. use map with dynamic keys (you known values are strings, so cast)
String value1 = (String) map.get("key1");
```

For a huge JSON array it would be rather ineffective (as it would create a huge number of singleton maps). So, solution proposed by @Eskapone (if you can alter the schema of input JSON) is better in these cases.